# java connecting to Oracle DB java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, oracle, swing

I am having the below problem with the code.

I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to connect and get data from the database. I get the error when the `executeQuery` is carried out I think. As far as I know the code is correct but the way to connect to the database as sys is still something I am not sure about.

here goes:

```
package masterdocument;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
public class JavaConnectDB {
public static Connection ConnecrDB(){
try{
    String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
    String nameForConnect = "sys as sysdba";
    String pass = "Abcd1234";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db01";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, nameForConnect, pass);
    System.out.println(conn);
    return conn;
    }
catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    return null;
    }    
 }
}
```

and the call to the connection above:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         

conn = JavaConnectDB.ConnecrDB();
        try{
            String sql="select * from TUTILIZADORES where USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?";
        pst.setString(1, USERNAME.getText());
        pst.setString(2, PASSWORD.getText());
        rs=(OracleResultSet)pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O username e password estavam bem");

        Tutilizadores c = new Tutilizadores();
        c.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Inválido");
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                        }       
}
```

I am somewhat new to Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the part that creates the `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql="select * from TUTILIZADORES where USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

You should also make sure to close this statement and the `ResultSet` after finishing with using them. You can do this in a `finally` block:

```
} catch(Exception e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,e);
} finally {
   if(rs != null) {
       rs.close();
   }
   if(pst != null) {
       pst.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have used     Connection conn=null;
    OraclePreparedStatement pst=null;
    OracleResultSet rs=null;

Comment: @AlexG See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: I have added : PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  and its working. Thank you Manouti!!